# Sony Spresense のリカバリーができない。　これは、ハード的に壊れたのでしょうか？

Tags: spresense, ハードウェア

Sony Spresense を　Arduino IDEから　プログラムの書き込みをして、利用していたのですが、　
ある時から急に応答しなくなりました。

拡張ボードの上で使っていましたが、電源の青色LEDが点灯していません。　
拡張ボードから何度か取り外したり、取り付けたりを繰り返したことで、プラのスペーサの足が伸びていたようです。

spresense本機が、拡張ボードのコネクタに綺麗に入っておらず、
ボードが少し浮き上がっているようでした。本機を押し込んだらLEDが点いたり消えたりしていました。

本機を拡張ボードから取り外して、
本機に直接USBで給電しましたが、LEDの青色は点灯しない状態のままです。
何かの拍子で　時々 点灯したりまた消えたりしています。　
点灯する要因はわかりません。コネクタの不良を疑って、usbマイクロケーブルのコネクタの根本をゆらゆらさせてみましたが
それでは、LEDは点灯はしないようです。コネクタのぐらつき　や　ハンダのクラックもなさそうです。

PCと本機をUSBケーブルで接続すると、PC上でComポートとして認識しています。　Arduino IDEから　ブートローダの書き込みをしてみましたが、しばらく待っても応答が帰ってきません。

Windowsのコマンドプロンプト（cmd.exe)から、recovery tool実行してみましたが、　
Comインターフェースは認識するけれども、　Please press RESET button ...  以降は、　
Spresense本機のリセットボタンとリカバリボタンの同時押しを　何度やっても、PC画面上のメッセージは先にすすみません。

このSpresense本機は、もはやハード的に壊れたと　考えた方がいいですか？
それとも、何か復活させるよい方法はありますか？

Comment: 基板をショートさせてしまったかなにかで壊れてしまった可能性が高いと思います。残念ながら。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。　やはりそうなんですね。　あきらめることにします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どんなことが起きてるのだろうと興味があり回路図を眺めて見ました。恐らく事象から察するにIC5のLDO(5V->4V)が壊れていると思います。回路図はここにあります。

https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-hw-design-files/blob/master/CXD5602PWBMAIN1/schematics/CXD5602PWBMAIN1_schematics.pdf

使用しているLDOのデータシートを見ると最大定格が6.0Vになっています。

https://www.n-redc.co.jp/ja/pdf/datasheet/rp115-ja.pdf

これから考えられるのは USBからの給電が6.0Vを（おそらく遥かに）越えてしまい、LDOが壊れてしまったということです。USB-PD規格にきちんと準拠していないアダプタもしくはバッテリを使用されたのではないかと…

Spreseseのサポートページにも次のような記述がありました。

「**[USB Type-C ACアダプタなどをmicroBへの変換アダプタを使用して SPRESENSEボードに電源供給を行うとVBUSの耐圧を超える電圧が 供給されてしまうことがあり、SPRESENSEボードを破壊する恐れがあります（Type-Cのレセプタクルコネクタを持つ変換アダプタはUSB規格非準拠品です）。](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/introduction_ja.html#_spresense_%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E9%9B%BB%E6%BA%90%E4%BE%9B%E7%B5%A6%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95spresense%E6%8B%A1%E5%BC%B5%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88)**」

Spresenseに限った話ではありませんが、USB3.0給電デバイスからUSB2.0デバイスに対する電源供給は気をつけたほうが良さそうですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
心当たりあります。 ご指摘に通りです。
USB-Cケーブルからマイクロへの変換コネクタを使ってました。 次から気をつけます。　破壊の連鎖を作らずに済みます。