# ArduinoIDEでWindows11のパソコンからspresenseに書き込もうとすると「Can not open port ...」のエラーが表示される

Tags: windows, spresense, arduino, usb

ArduinoIDEを使用してspresenseにコードを書き込んだりブートローダーを利用したりすると"Can not open port"のエラーが出るようになってしまいました。このエラーが表示されてしまうまでの流れと、やってみた対策をお話しします。

今までArduinoIDEでspresenseにコードを書き込み、接続したセンサーの値を取得できていました。しかし10月の中旬ごろからコードを書き込もうとすると以下のような表示がされるようになりました。

```
Cannot open port : COM3
could not open port 'COM3': FileNotFoundError(2, '�w�肳�ꂽ�t�@�C�������‚���܂���B', None, 2)
could not open port 'COM3': FileNotFoundError(2, '�w�肳�ꂽ�t�@�C�������‚���܂���B', None, 2)
```

上記のエラーに対して、次のような方法を行ってみました。
・書き込むPC(Windows11)の再起動
・spresenseが壊れていることを疑い、別のspresenseに書き込もうとした → 同じエラーが表示
・USBドライバ(CP210x_Universal_Windows_Driver)の再インストール
・Arduino IDEをMicrosoft Storeから再インストール
・Arduino IDEを公式サイトからインストール
・書き込む速度を遅めに設定
・Arduino IDEのポート番号を、PCのデバイスマネージャーで確認したポート番号に設定　&　他のポート番号でも試してみた
などといった対応をしてみましたが、依然として同じエラーが表示され続けます。
以前まで問題なく利用できていたのにエラーが発生してしまったので理由がわからないです。もし解決策をご存じの方がいればご教授お願い致します。

Comment: かつて `COM3` であったシリアルポートが `COM4` とか名前が変わったんでしょう（ USB HUB の差す場所が変わったとか何とかの理由で）デバイスマネージャからポートを開いて、ポート名を再確認。

Comment: デバイスマネージャーで確認したポート番号と、Arduino IDEで設定しているポート番号は同じCOM3になっています。

Comment: デバイスマネージャー上で、USBケーブルを抜いたらきちんとCOM3は消えますか?

Comment: はい。USBケーブルを抜いたらデバイスマネージャでも表示は消えます。なので余計謎が深まってます。

Answer (score 0):

SPRESENSEのメイン基板のResetスイッチがある右側の青色PowerLED(※D2)はついていますか？
ここがついていないと、USBケーブルのVBUSなどから作られるACP_PWRが供給されていないといえます。

comポート自体への応答は、USB-UART変換IC(IC5)が担うのでCOMポートは見えますが、VBUSからの電流がLDO(IC6)で生成されてACP_PWRが作られると思いますので、以下の過去の情報のように電流ショートや過電流をかけたなどでHWの故障など問題が発生している可能性があります。

[https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/82885/sony-spresense-のリカバリーができない-これは-ハード的に壊れたのでしょうか](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/82885/sony-spresense-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AB%E3%83%90%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AF-%E3%83%8F%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AB%E5%A3%8A%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B)?

※：メイン基板回路図での番号
位置は、以下のPowerLED
[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/introduction_ja.html#_spresense_メインボード](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/introduction_ja.html#_spresense_%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89)